# How to install proproetary 352 nvidia driver

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, cuda, gpu-driver

I need to be able to use cuda 7.5. As I understand it needs the latest proprietary nvidia driver which is 352 for my gt740m. This driver comes along with cuda toolkit but it doesn't work. Just doesn't see my card. So I tried to install it from this ppa `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` but it seems to be open source and cuda still says `CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version`. Then I tried to install it from .run file which I got [here](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/92826/en-us) but it failed with `kernel module failed to build`. Is there any way to install it?

Answer (score 0):

From the Dash, run the "Software Updater", and select the "Settings" button.  Under the "Ubuntu Software" tab, ensure the "Proprietary Drivers" is checked.  Under the "Additional Drivers" tab, see if the 352 driver is offered.  That is the best way to install a proprietary driver.